# How to show 2 scene side by side in asciimatics

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm try to use asciimatics for a TUI, which will be the front end for a test frame work. The TUI should have some parameters that are constant and are common for all tests, and another section where there are parameters based on the selected test.

I'm pretty sure I can get this to work if I create a main frame for the common parameters, and frames for each individual test, then, based on the selected test open the specific test frame when the user clicks a button to edit test parameters.

However, I would much rather have the test parameters shown along side the common ones. I was thinking about putting the second frame inside a layout, and swapping it on the fly when the selected test is changed. Is this possible to do with asciimatics?

Thanks,
o

Answer (score 0):

As documented in https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/widgets.html#layouts-in-more-detail, a `Layout` belongs inside a `Frame`.  You can't put a `Frame` in side a `Layout`.

However, there is no reason you can't just use two `Frames` next to each other.  Simply create them with the right size and locations to be side by side.